# IPFS on OpenBSD

Tags: openbsd

How can I install IPFS on OpenBSD?

https://ipfs.io/
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InterPlanetary_File_System

> InterPlanetary File System (IPFS) is a protocol designed to create a
>   permanent and decentralized method of storing and sharing files. It is
>   a content-addressable, peer-to-peer hypermedia distribution protocol.
>   Nodes in the IPFS network form a distributed file system. IPFS is an
>   open-source project developed since 2014 by Protocol Labs with help
>   from the open-source community.

Comment: It might help if you explained what is IPFS, what did you try, and where did you get stuck.

Comment: Not with the meaningful parts though. _shrug_

Comment: https://github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/blob/master/docs/openbsd.md

Answer (score 2):

I imported go-ipfs (`net/go-ipfs`) into OpenBSD ports a few months back, so you can install from packages.